# How to cancel a firebase StorageTask?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm uploading some images to firebase storage and I need to cancel the process whenever the cancel button is clicked, but I can't handle cancellation and app crashes out. Here is my code and logcat error:

**The code:**

```
buttonCancel.setOnClickListener{
     uploadTask.cancel()
}

val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
for (path in pathsList){
        val imgRef = storageRef.child("${Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis}.jpg")
        val fileUri = Uri.fromFile(File(path))
        uploadTask = imgRef.putFile(fileUri)
        try {
            uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener {
                p0 -> val downloadUri = p0.result.toString()
                //do sth with download uri
            }
        }
        catch (ex: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, "upload canceled", Toas.LENGHT_SHORT).show
            break
        }
}
```

**Logcat error:**

```
08-25 18:20:59.149 22419-23332/packagename E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
The operation was cancelled.
 Code: -13040 HttpResult: 0
08-25 18:20:59.158 22419-22419/packagename D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-25 18:20:59.161 22419-22419/packagename E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: packagename, PID: 22419
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: The operation was cancelled.
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at packagename.myFragment$myMethod$1$1.onComplete(myFragment.kt:348)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzq.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzaf.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
 Caused by: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: The operation was cancelled.
    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.onCanceled(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzk(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzx.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
08-25 18:20:59.428 22419-23333/packagename E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
```

How can I catch this exception?(Please note that I'm doing this in a for loop, I don't know it may make differrence)

Comment: What's the full error in the logs, not just the first line?  What lines does it point to in your code?

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

do like this in on failure upload do what you want

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return postImageUri.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        //getting url
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //failure to get the url
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // here you will get the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't catch the exception. Is this `try{throw e}catch(ex: Exception){}` the right way to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling getResult() in your onCompleteListener when there is no result available to get.  Instead, you should replace your onCompleteListener (which receives all results, both success and failure) into an onSuccessListener and an onFailureListener.  The onSuccessListener will only receive results that are successful, so you can always safely call getResult() without throwing an exception.

Please read the [Play Services Task API documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) for more details on how tasks work.